# button/menu in title bar on each windows explore

Tags: .net, button

i want to create a button/menu in title bar on each windows explore(or in browser).how can be done this in .net c# ? any idea please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a toolbar and add it to Explorer. [Extending Explorer with Band Objects using .NET and Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx)